# MS Access 2000 (*mdb) default value of Now() sometimes fails?

Tags: ms-access, visual-c++, ms-access-2000

Is there a known failure mode of a MS Access 2000 database, when data is refused (or silently discarded, which is worse) to be inserted into a table containing a Date/Time type of field with default value of =Now() ?

The date/time field in question is not indexed or required;

But when an INSERT query is sent to the database, it looks like the =Now() function fails - and the data is not written to the table (however another auto-increment field lookup is executed, because, when later on =Now() succeeds, there is a gap in auto-increments, equal to the number of times the query was run)

e.g. i see in the table

```
ID | Data | Timestamp
5  | foo  | 11/15/2016 17:15:00
1  | foo  | 11/15/2016 17:11:00
```

when an `INSERT INTO TheTable ([Data]) VALUES (foo)` is ran every minute and the problem happens on run 2, 3 and 4. Eventually after some time, it succeeds (as shown with ID=5)

Why do I think it could be the =Now() problem ?

Because same/similar failure happens if computer clock is changed /backwards/ (e.g. during DST adjustment).

But it has recently happened just out of the blue, not being able to write data to that table for a couple of hours, when the DST adjustment has actually happened already.

(the program itself is not being told of the query failure and charges forward as if nothing happened - some debugging effort is pending still)

I looked about SO and wonder if this [Table Field Default Property Values Functions Not Working Anymore in Microsoft Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052776/table-field-default-property-values-functions-not-working-anymore-in-microsoft-a) may have something to do with it? However the program and the database communicate via ODBC Microsoft Access (*.mdb) driver (yes MS Office 2000 files...)

Hope this makes sense,
Kind Regards...

Answer (score 1):

Have never heard of such issue, but why not just adjust your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TheTable ([Data], [Timestamp]) VALUES (foo, Now())
```

Comment: That I'm going to.

Comment: Also maybe create a test/fallback routine that verifies whether the row has been inserted, and tries to insert it again if it can't be retrieved, but using its own way to retrieve current date/time. It's hard to debug this, cause it never happens on the test bed... Anyway, thanks !